# Перевод формата даты mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(), DATE_FORMAT('26.09.2015 00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")) as seconds
```

Нужно перевести формат даты в запросе, что-бы корректно посчитать разницу в секундах, такой способ возвращает NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(), STR_TO_DATE('26.09.2015 00:00', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')) as seconds
```